# Seeking data of geographical electricity consumption per area/district in any region of the world

Tags: geospatial, energy

I am trying to find if any electric utility (I don't mind which one) provides geographical information about elecricity consumption per area, discrict, etc.

For instance, the company which distributes electricity in a certain country publishes that the consumption in the district A is 500 MWh per year, in the district B is 640 MWh per year, etc.

If it exists, I would be very grateful if you could provide the source (Internet address, person to contact, etc.). Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Electricity consumption dataset](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/9148/electricity-consumption-dataset)

Answer (score 2):

The electricity consumption in France is available at https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/consommation-et-production-delectricite-en-temps-reel/#_ -> export CSV (updated every hour).

Answer (score 2):

In the Netherlands energy companies publish electricity consumption for postcode areas. On this website http://www.energieinbeeld.nl/open-data-kleinverbruiksgegevens-netbeheerders/ there are links to the company webpages. Unfortunately it's in Dutch.